# Nginx SSL pass-through based on uri path

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxy

I'd like to know if it is possible to configure Nginx to dynamically send request (without SSL termination) to given microservice?

In my architecture I have two microservices. Lets assume that they are localhost:5000 and localhost:5100. I'd like to send all request (that come to Nginx proxy) that start with `/api` to localhost:5000 and `/services` to localhost:5100. I have configured SSL on both microservices so I do not need SSL termination on Nginx.

Is this possible?

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to show any real [research](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) - for example, nginx's [example server blocks](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/) has an example showing the use of two different location blocks to achieve something similar in spirit to what you are describing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are asking to do is impossible. This is not a limitation of Nginx, rather it is a consequence of how SSL works.

Passing a connection through a load balancer without terminating SSL requires the load balancer to choose a backend before it will be able to forward the ServerHello message from the server back to the client. However at that early stage the client has not yet send the URI, so it cannot be used in the choice of backend.

The alternatives you have are as follows:

- Terminate SSL on the load balancer.
- Host the services on two different IP addresses.
- Host the services on two different port numbers.
- Host the services on two different domain names.

If you have a hard requirement for the URLs to use a specific domain and no port number in the URLs, most of those options will be eliminated and terminating SSL on the load balancer will be your only option.

The reason I distinguish between using two different IP address and using two different domain names is that two domain names pointing to the same IP address is a possibility, but only as long as the clients support SNI. (In that scenario you can only make one of the domains work for clients without SNI).

Answer (score 2):

No, not quite how you've said you want it to work. However there are ways to do it.

Nginx can do [TCP load balancing](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/tcp-load-balancing/), no problem. That allows passing connections through without terminating SSL/TLS. However at that layer of the network stack (layer 4, [transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)) there's no knowledge of URIs. You can't use URLs to balance TCP connections, you'd need Nginx listening to different ports. That might be a good enough solution for you.

The better way to do it, if it suited your application, would be to move up from layer 4 to layer 7. Nginx could be to terminate SSL/TLS on the load balancer then let Nginx call the microservices. The microservices calls can be http or https. There's a [guide here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/load-balancer/).